# Application.ScreenUpdate and Shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that I have a bunch of shapes (rectangle = button) that have marcos assigned to. I am using the shapes as a userform. There is one button that toggles between forms (essentially hiding all the visible shapes then showing all the shapes for another setup). The issue that I am having is that during the switch over to the other setup the shapes from the first setup still appear throughout the transition even though I am using:
`Application.ScreenUpdate=False`

I am trying to have a clean transition / clean switch over. Any thoughts? If my question is not clear, please let me know.

Sample Code

```
Sub Toggle_Form
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call Form1_ShowHide(False)
Call Form2_ShowHide(True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sub Form1_ShowHide(VisibleState as boolean)
For CoUnTer = 1 To 10
    WS.Shapes("Shape1_" & CoUnTer).Visible = VisibleState
Next CoUnTer
End Sub

Sub Form2_ShowHide(VisibleState as boolean)
For CoUnTer = 1 To 20
    WS.Shapes("Shape2_" & CoUnTer).Visible = VisibleState
Next CoUnTer
End Sub
```

I am using Excel 2016. Do not think it is a computer processing issue (got a pretty good laptop).

Comment: Well first of all shapes are not made to build userforrms. I recommend to use a real userform instead as you can easily run into odd issues with this approach. Further the `Shapes.Visible` property does not use `False`/`True` but `msoFalse`/`msoTrue`. Actually I cannot reproduce the issue with your example. Note that `Sub Toggle_Form` is missing a `End Sub` and therefore the code cannot work as shown.

Comment: Oh man, you are missing out on using shapes as a userform. It gives you the flexibility to create a highly customizable form as opposed to extremely limited options within Excel. I can make interfaces that are close to App interfaces. I have also tried msoF/T with the same results.

Comment: Well, it comes with all the downsides of using shapes. As I said this is a mis-use as shapes were not intended for that purpose. That means it might not work as you expected. Actually I cannot reproduce the issue with that code: It works. So if you face an issue it is not in this code. • I recommend to re-think what is more worthy: A fancy userinterface for an Excel sheet or a more old fashioned looking but definitly working and easier maintainable userform that comes without any odd issues and less errors.

Comment: I definitely understand it was not really designed for that function. But Microsoft allows you to assign marcos to shapes. So I am taking advantage of that. Just as a disclaimer - the code above is a simple version of what I am doing. There is much more shapes and each shape has a unique name. So some of code is in the form of a For Loop as described above and some is a direct command to a specific shape. For example: WS.Shapes("Apartments").Visible = VisibleState. Guessing it could be an issue with my computer.

Comment: Since the issue is not reproducable we probably cannot help.